# How to get information about error from SqlExceptionHelper for REST spring application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have some tables in my database and I want to get information about wrong requests to the database. In case If I'm trying to save entity with wrong foreigns keys, I want to get detail information about these keys.

For example:

```
2020-03-25 18:37:37.595 ERROR 9788 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: insert or update on table "student" violates foreign key constraint "student_fkey_to_specialty"
  Detail: Key (specialtykey)=(2) is not present in table "specialty".
```

I tried to solve with this code, but I get other information.

```
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [student_fkey_to_specialty]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

my code:

```
@PostMapping
    public void saveStudent(@RequestBody StudentDTO studentDTO) {
        if(studentDTO!=null){
            try {
                studentService.save(studentDTO);

            }catch (Exception|Error e){
                throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, e.getLocalizedMessage(),e );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you're looking at the top-level exception. You might want to loop to the original exception using [`getCause`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause--).

Comment: @second Nice, e.getCause().getCause().getLocalizedMessage() works!

Answer (score 3):

Use a loop to iterate to the original exception,
here a example function that does that:

```java
private String getCauseMessage(Throwable t)

    Throwable cause = t;
    while (t.getCause() != null) {
        cause = t.getCause();
    }

    return t.getLocalizedMessage();
}
```

As you never know how many exception might be chained together, using a loop is the safest way. If you just use it directly you risk getting a `NullPointerException` or
not getting the message of the original exception.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem with this code. This allows getting information about exceptions from the database.

```
e.getCause().getCause().getLocalizedMessage()
```

Comment: Your really want to use a loop here. There is no guarantee that there will always be exactly two causes.

Comment: @second How to fix it?

Comment: I've added an answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Student table is having "student_fkey_to_specialty" which is getting violated. Check on which filed this constraint is and provide the correct value for that field

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm little late. I was facing the same problem and I could solve it using DataAccessException instead of just an Exception as a parameter of catch. DataAccessException provides a getMostSpecificCause method, which has the same information from SqlExceptionHelper.

I've rewritten your method using DataAccessException:

```
@PostMapping
public void saveStudent(@RequestBody StudentDTO studentDTO) {
    if(studentDTO!=null){
        try {
            studentService.save(studentDTO);

        }catch (DataAccessException e){
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, e.getMostSpecificCause().getLocalizedMessage(), e );
        }
    }
}
```